# How transactions are signed by multiple parties in cordapp?

Tags: corda

When transactions need to be signed by multiple parties in cordapp, how they are singed ??
They manually sign off cordapp?? Or Is there some api which supports sign by multiple parties??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please spend some time exploring this example: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example

- The initiating node signs the transaction: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L85
- The initiating node requests signatures from other participants: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L91
- Other nodes (in responding flow) sign the transaction: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L112